# `arr.length` works outside a loop but causes an error inside a loop

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to complete a hackerrank challenge.When I try to use `puts arr.length` in the loop,

```
n = gets.strip.to_i
arr = gets.strip
arr = arr.split(' ').map(&:to_i)
n.times do |i|
  puts arr.length
  arr = arr[i] - 2
  if arr[i] <= 0
    arr[i].delete
  end
end
```

I get an error:

```
!in `block in': undefined method `length' for 3:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

I don't understand it because `arr.length` works outside the loop. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Thanks for helping me discover that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reassigning `arr` as a `Fixnum` here: `arr = arr[i] - 2`. Hence the error

Answer (score 1):

you've reassigned to `arr` inside the loop, I assume the first pass through the loop has worked but on the second pass, `arr` is now an integer.

You should use a different variable name that is uniq inside the loop